# How do I dynamically build a valid JSON structure, like the following pseudo structure?

Tags: javascript, json

sorry for the imprecise question, but I dont find a solution. I dynamically want to to create the following JSON structure. The reason for the structure is that I want to give every nested object a unique id, to get easy access.

My first question is, why this JSON is not valid and what I need to change and the second question is how I dynamically can create the object with JavaScript?

```
{
"data": [

    "object_1": {
        "key1": "value",
        "key2": "value",
        "key3": "value"
    },
    "object_2": {
        "key1": "value",
        "key2": "value",
        "key3": "value"
    },
    "object_3": {
        "key1": "value",
        "key2": "value",
        "key3": "value"
    }
    
]
}
```

Comment: Well the fact you do not have a `{` and `}` makes it invalid. How to generate it? How do you push objects to an array? I am not sure what is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

that's not how an array structure works, this is probably what you want

```
{
"data": [

    {"object_1": {
        "key1": "value",
        "key2": "value",
        "key3": "value"
    }},
    {"object_2": {
        "key1": "value",
        "key2": "value",
        "key3": "value"
    }},
    {"object_3": {
        "key1": "value",
        "key2": "value",
        "key3": "value"
    }}
    
]
}
```

you have to enclose your object

Comment: Unfortunately with this way I dont have an accessible key, for my easy access. I would have to loop through the data array, until I find my ID

Comment: in javascript you dont have associative arrays you have objects and to find the object with the right value you will always have to loop there is though really simple functions in js to find the value your looking for filter and find for example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want each object stored in an array for easy access right? The solution is making a class for that :D

Example below

```js
class Storage{
  constructor(){
    this.data=[]
  }
  addItem(newObj){
    if(typeof newObj!="object"){
      throw new Error("I store objects an arrays, nothing else")
    }
    if(this.data.includes(newObj)){
      throw new Error("object already exists")
    }
    return this.data.push(newObj)-1
  }
  getItem(index){
    if(typeof index!="number"){
      throw new Error("your parameter of search MUST be a number")
    }
    if(!this.data[index]){
      throw new Error(index+" is an invalid index")
    }
    return this.data[index]
  }
}

//example usage
var obj1={a:1,b:2,c:[3,4]}
var obj2=[1,2,3,4,5]

let storage=new Storage()
let location1=storage.addItem(obj1)
let location2=storage.addItem(obj2)
console.log({location1,location2})

let found1=storage.getItem(location1)
let found2=storage.getItem(location2)
console.log("does found1==obj1?",found1==obj1)
console.log("does found2==obj2?",found2==obj2)
```

Comment: No, like I said, I need JSON :) And I dont want to use a simple array because I dont want to loop it every time to find my id. Thats the reason, I want to have a specific key-name

Comment: @gear JSON means JavaScript Object Notation. Fancy words for the stringed form of an object. Also, an array IS an object where the keys are the indexes.. you do not need to loop through the array, as when you add an item, the key/index is returned to you.. can you look at the implementation again ;-;